# How to force invalidate ProgressDialog on Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, progressdialog

I'm doing some tasks in background thread and show progress using `ProgressDialog` (both message and progress). I'm sure it works okay and update is done in UI thread.

When update is done very frequently it invalidates dialog view only few times a second (not after every message/progress setting). How can i force update it every time message or progress is changed? I can't find any `getView()` or `invalidate()` method.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

You can change it as per your requirement.

```
            @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try {
                publishProgress("Connecting");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                publishProgress("Downloading");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                publishProgress("Done");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
        {
            mProgressHUD.setMessage(values[0]);
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't a `ProgressDialog` take number values?

Comment: Why not? Its just an example.

Comment: @4ntoine: do you want like this or have prob something else?

Comment: >> I'm sure it works okay and update is done in UI thread. This means my code already does what you wrote. It's another problem. Updated message (text and progress) is not shown right after it's set

Comment: Then you have to post more code related to your problem.

Comment: ProgressDialog dialog = ...; // progressDialog.setMessage(currentMessage); // not updated